# Facebook share showing error 'Given URL is not allowed '

Tags: facebook, api

I tried the following code for facebook share

```
<p>
<a  rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class=" icon_facebook ">Share</a>
</p>




jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });
};

//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 jQuery('.icon_facebook').click(
function(){
    FB.ui(
      {
    method: 'share',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'

},
function(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('Post was published.');
  } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
  }
}
)

});

}

);
```

then it showing error .

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains.

And the share url in both facebook all ready logined and logout condition is like  `https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/share?app_id=MY APP ID ,.....`
But in other websites the working share page url format is different . When not login then it shows like

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=..
```

when some one already login to the faccebook it shows like `https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/share?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Freturn%2Fclose&display=popup&href=`

> Why my facebook share url is different ? is am missing any code part ?

Is there any mistake in my code ? please help .

Comment: The obvious question:  you have the correct appId in FB init?

Comment: Yes .It is correct .

Comment: OK, but is the link you are trying to share from the same domain as listed in the App settings (under App Domains)?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. I write wrong appId. Thank you for saying .

Comment: You can post it as answer . Because people need to know this.

Comment: But some time it showing The parameter app_id is required . But i refresh 2, 3 time then it will ok .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

1. Make sure you have the correct appId in FB init; and
2. The shared URL must be listed in the App Domains input under App Settings on your Dveloper console in Facebook.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. I write wrong appId. It is working now .  
But some time it showing The parameter app_id is required . But i refresh 2, 3 time then it will ok